# HeatMap not displaying correctly using ggplot()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, heatmap

I am having a strange situation when I am trying to plot a heatmap on a dataset that I have which can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B26EL85v1mxnVGZZTlZvbmRQN0U/).

I am using the following code to plot the heat map:

```
xaxis<-c('density')
midrange<-range(red[,xaxis])
xaxis <- c(xaxis,'quality')
molten<-melt(red[,xaxis],'quality')

p <- ggplot(molten, aes(x = value, y = quality))
p <- p + geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white")
p <- p + theme_minimal()

# turn y-axis text 90 degrees (optional, saves space)
p <- p + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5))

# remove axis titles, tick marks, and grid
p <- p + theme(axis.title = element_blank())
p <- p + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
p <- p + theme(panel.grid = element_blank())

p <- p + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) 
# optionally remove row labels (not useful depending on molten)
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) 

# get diverging color scale from colorbrewer
# #008837 is green, #7b3294 is purple
palette <- c("#008837", "#b7f7f4", "#b7f7f4", "#7b3294")


if(midrange[1] == midrange[2]) {
  # use a 3 color gradient instead
  p <- p + scale_fill_gradient2(low = palette[1], mid = palette[2], high = palette[4], midpoint = midrange[1]) +
    xlim(midrange[1],midrange[2])
}else{
  # use a 4 color gradient (with a swath of white in the middle)
  p <- p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = palette, values = c(0, midrange[1], midrange[2], 1)) +
    xlim(midrange[1],midrange[2])
}
p
```

I am trying to plot the heat map on the variable `Density` and would like to use the variable `quality` as separation in my heat map. When I use the above code, I get the following plot:

[image]

It can be clearly seen that it is a blank image. This is happening because the range of the variable `Density` is very low, it doesn't happen if I change the variable to the one having a wider range (`pH` for example).
Should ggplot automatically adjust to this? If not, how can I get ggplot to show the real plot?

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are (at least) two problems here.

First, you have almost 1600 tiles in the x-direction, so specifying `color="white"` for the outline means that *all you see is the outline*, hence, white. Try taking this out.

Second, in your `values=c(...)` argument to `scale_fill_gradientn(...)` you seem to expect the `midrange[1]` and `midrange[2]` to be between (0,1), but `midrange[2] = 1.003`.

After taking out `color="white"` from the call to `geom_tile(...)`, I get this:

[image]